# Angular2: Scrolling randomly not working

Tags: angular, browser, scroll

Im developing a fairly complicated web application using Angular2. 
I've run into an annoying problem: From time to time scrolling up and down does not work.

There is no errors or anything to indicate why this problems occurs. Only solution is to refresh the page, and scrolling will work again. 
This problem has been observed in all major browsers (Safari, Chrome, and Firefox).

Does anyone know what might be the root of this problem?

Comment: are you loading too much data on your main thread?

Comment: I will test if the data load is high on main thread. I do not think its the problem, but I will test.

Comment: perhaps you should buy a new mouse :D?

Comment: LOL I wish that was the problem, but it's not :(